# how to add condition to delete last character in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

```
ID   |  OSTag
2145 |  BMV123456,BMV234567,BMV123789,BMV124654,BMV456234, BMV908567,
5437 |  DAD676776,DAD989898,DAD787656,
5452 |  DAD123456,
```

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT bag2.PassengerID,
( SELECT bag1.OSTag +',' AS [text()] FROM REZP8OD01.dbo.Baggage bag1
WHERE bag1.PassengerID=bag2.PassengerID
ORDER BY bag1.PassengerID FOR XML PATH(''))[OSTag] FROM dbo.Baggage bag2
```

Now I want to add check condition into my sql query that if last item of column OSTag then remove character ','.

```
Output result like this:
ID   |  OSTag
2145 |  BMV123456,BMV234567,BMV123789,BMV124654,BMV456234, BMV908567
5437 |  DAD676776,DAD989898,DAD787656
5452 |  DAD123456
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     bag2.PassengerID
    ,STUFF(( SELECT ',' + bag1.OSTag  AS [text()] 
       FROM REZP8OD01.dbo.Baggage bag1
       WHERE bag1.PassengerID=bag2.PassengerID
       ORDER BY bag1.PassengerID FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'') [OSTag] 

FROM dbo.Baggage bag2
```

Or even better would be

```
SELECT bag2.PassengerID
    ,STUFF(( SELECT ',' + bag1.OSTag 
             FROM REZP8OD01.dbo.Baggage bag1
             WHERE bag1.PassengerID=bag2.PassengerID
             ORDER BY bag1.PassengerID 
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,1,'') [OSTag] 
FROM dbo.Baggage bag2
GROUP BY bag2.PassengerID
```

### [`SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/2698)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a number of ways. Probably the easiest is using LEFT.

```
select LEFT(OSTag, len(OSTag) - 1)
```

I have to mention that storing delimited values in a single column violates 1NF and is a serious pain to deal with.

Comment: Can you add it into my quey for me? Please

Comment: Using STUFF as M.Ali posted is a bit easier since you are using FOR XML here.